# KnockoutJS: template is not updated on observable array change (only on add, works on remove)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So, I have observable array with sites, which is shown via template. If I'll add site to this array, template is not updated, but if I'll remove site from array – voila! template became updated and all previously added sites became displayed too.

If I'll use nifty hack (commented in code) with replacement of whole array to new one then everything works.

BTW, I load template via AJAX and use "ko.applyBindings(viewModel)" after. I assume that works fine, because initial sites are displayed correctly.

```
$(function(){

//site entry in user's sites list
var siteObject = function(url, lastChecked, status){
    this.url = url;
    this.lastChecked = (lastChecked == 'undefined') ? '' : lastChecked;
    this.status = (status == 'undefined') ? 'not_checked_yet' : status;
    this.toDelete = false;
    this.remove = function() {viewModel.sites.remove(this)};
};

viewModel = {
    //=========== sites list managment ==========================
    sites: ko.observableArray(),
    //on "add" click in "add site" form
    addSite: function(){
        var $form = $('#add_site_form');
        var siteUrl = $form.find('input[name="site"]').val();

        /*nifty hack  <----
        var sites = this.sites();
        sites.push(new siteObject(siteUrl));
        this.sites(sites);*/

        this.sites.push(new siteObject(siteUrl));
    },
    //on "remove sites" button click
    removeSites: function() {
        var sitesToRemove = [];
        $.each(this.sites(), function(){
            if (this.toDelete) sitesToRemove.push(this);
        });
        if (sitesToRemove.length == 0)
            alert("Ни одного сайта не было выбрано для удаления.");
        else {
            var message = "Вы точно хотите перестать отслеживать";
            for (var i in sitesToRemove) {
                message += "\n\"" +  sitesToRemove[i].url + "\"";
            }
            message += "?";
            if (confirm(message)) {
                $.each(sitesToRemove, function(){this.remove()});
                //save new sites list to db
                this.saveSitesListToDb();
            }
        }   
        //hide form
        $('#remove_sites_form').slideToggle();
        //toggle checkboxes
        $('#content_sites_list .site_info input[type="checkbox"]').slideToggle();
    };
```

And the template:

```
<!-- end of menu -->
<div id="content_sites_list" 
     class="grid_12" 
     data-bind="template: {name: 'sites_list_template', foreach: sites}"></div>

  <!-- Templates -->

  <script id="sites_list_template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="site">
        <div class="site_panel grid_12">
            <div class="site_info">
                &ndash;
                <input type="checkbox" value="${url}" 
                       class="delete_checkbox" data-bind="checked: toDelete" /> 
                <a href="${url}" class="show_site_stat">${url.substr(7)}</a>
                {{if status == "200"}}
                    <img src="img/green_light.png" alt="ok"/>
                {{/if}}             
            </div>
            <div class="site_stat">
                <div class="site_last_check">Последняя проверка: ${dateTimestamp}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

I've tried this on latest beta on knockoutjs and on stable one.

Comment: If you change `this.sites.push(new siteObject(siteUrl));` to `sites.push(new siteObject(siteUrl));` does it make any difference?

Comment: Yes, it won't work) this.sites() - is knockout's observable array. sites - is local array created from observable array + new object.

Comment: Your example works fine for me after small edits, including correctly closing curly and round braces in $(function() {}).

By the way I think it is better to make siteUrl the member of the view model and then bind it to some checkbox instead of searching it with jQuery selectors.

Comment: @STO thank you, I'll surely try it. This is my first project with MVVM.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/majorbyte/9gM7N/) which works fine.

There were some problems that JSLint was complaining about in the `removeSites` function of the viewModel. I fixed those and added a button and input field to be able to give some input, and everything ran smooth.

So you could try updating your `removeSites` function and see if it helps you,

Comment: wow, thx! Seems like the problem is in AJAXed template, because your code is quite similar to mine. I'll try to include it in index page. Also I will try to use knockout's new template engine in 1.3.0